# JavaScript Split on Any Number of a Character

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to split on any number of a character in JavaScript, possibly with a regex?

**Example:**

"These are ____ underscores" will return `["These are ", " underscores"]`

Here's what I have so far:

```
"These are ____ underscores".split("_").filter(x => x);
```

However, I am not sure if there is a more efficient/better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let x = 'These are ____ underscores';
let y = x.split(/_+/);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Note that if you have something like `let x = '__These are ____ underscores__';` maybe you want a `.filter(Boolean)` after `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by the character and then filter the non empty arrays:

```
var str = "These are ____ underscores"
str.split("_").filter(x => x.length)
```